# How to save marks in less for later access?

Tags: less

If I mark a line in less, the mark will lost when the current less session ends.

So, let's say, if I often check the bash man page for READLINE section, I have to search `^REA` every time.

Seems like less doesn't have any config files. Is there a way to save the marks in less so I can use it for next time?

Answer (score 0):

Not in the version of `less` I looked at. Another problem is that `man` may write to temporary files, so how would the marks line up between `/tmp/man.sLCaUQkJ3k` and `/tmp/man.yuvNSUrFZo` even if they were being saved?

We can cheat a little and use `vim` which does with suitable configuration save marks for future use, and also use the same filename for each `man` page. Note that a system-wide temporary directory would most likely be a very bad place to put static filenames, unless you like generating new CVE.

```
function mman {
   man "$1" | col -bx > "$HOME/tmp/man.$1"
   vim -R "$HOME/tmp/man.$1"
   #rm "$HOME/tmp/man.$1"
}
```

The generated page could either be removed immediately, or maybe a cron job cleans them up. Another problem is that man section names or other arguments to `man` are not supported, so this code may likely need to be complicated to handle `man 3 rand` the same as `man rand` (though those two may not be the same depending on your system and whether the OpenSSL `rand` man page intrudes).

Comment: Please specify your version of `less`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to preserve the marks across invocations... But:

> So, let's say, if I often check the bash man page for READLINE section, I have to search `^REA` every time.

`less` saves search history by default. It stores it in `~/.lesshst`, which can be overridden by setting the `$LESSHISTFILE` environment variable to point to another file's path. So at least you can use that to search for a regexp you used before (assuming you're using that same one often.) I hope you might find that useful (in case you didn't know about it.)